# What happens to a Maxwell-Boltzmann speed distribution when samples mix?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, speed, kinetic-theory

I have a few questions related to how it changes when two samples mix.

1. How would it change if two identical samples, one with higher KEavg and one with lower KEavg are added together? would the peak fall between the two peaks and the avg speed be exactly in between them?
2. How would this change if the samples weren't identical? What would happen if one of the samples, say the hotter/faster one had more mass? What if it had more particles?

Comment: I would start by looking up things like collisional relaxation and transport theory to get a cursory idea of these processes.  I suggest as much only because these questions can actually involve a tremendous amount of work and nuance to address.